# EDE load project

Tags: cedet, project

I'm running emacs 24.5.1 under windows 7 and I'm trying to figure out how EDE works and I have a problem, I don't understand how to load the project.

I've created Project.ede file like:

```
;; Object vmic
;; EDE Project Files are auto generated: Do Not Edit
(ede-proj-project "vmic"
  :file "Project.ede"
  :name "vmic"
  :targets
  (list
    (ede-proj-target-makefile-program "PP-build"
      :name "PP-build"
      :path ""
      :source '("platform/PP/src/pmain.c")
      :configuration-variables nil))
  :configuration-variables nil)
```

And on this stage everything looks fine. Then I'm saving the project buffers and restarting emacs. Go to menu -> "load project" -> selecting directory of Project.ede and nothing. It returns me an error "*Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil*".

Ok, I tried to create myproject.el file with content:

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "test"
                      :file "c:/Users/user/Desktop/test/Project.ede"
                      :include-path '("/" "/common/inc" "/common/src")
                      )
```

And again nothing. But if I'm trying now to load the project again it says that project is already loaded:
"*ede: c:/Users/user/Desktop/test/ already has an open project associated with it*"

So, what Am I missing Here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CEDET_Quickstart

Just add these strings to init.el and "load project" will work:

```
(require 'cedet)
(require 'eieio)
(require 'eieio-speedbar)
(require 'eieio-opt)
(require 'eieio-base)
(require 'ede/source)
(require 'ede/base)
(require 'ede/auto)
(require 'ede/proj)
(require 'ede/proj-archive)
(require 'ede/proj-aux)
(require 'ede/proj-comp)
(require 'ede/proj-elisp)
(require 'ede/proj-info)
(require 'ede/proj-misc)
(require 'ede/proj-obj)
(require 'ede/proj-prog)
(require 'ede/proj-scheme)
(require 'ede/proj-shared)
```

after **sr-speedbar-toggle** then **ede-speedbar** and voilà all you targets and connected files in front of you.